# JS - Reset timer when click

Tags: javascript

I have a 5 minutes countdown. This function launch automatically when page load. I want to reload data of page and resetting this countdown. The code looks like this.

HTML

```
  <a onClick="timer()" title="Pincha para actualizar" class="pull-right" id="time"></a>
```

JS

```
function timer(){
    var timer = 60 * 5, minutes, seconds;
    setInterval(function () {
        minutes = parseInt(timer / 60, 10)
        seconds = parseInt(timer % 60, 10);

        minutes = minutes < 10 ? "0" + minutes : minutes;
        seconds = seconds < 10 ? "0" + seconds : seconds;

        $('#time').text("Tiempo restante para actualización de datos " + minutes + ":" + seconds);

        if (--timer < 0) {
            timer = duration;
        }
    }, 1000);
}
```

The problem: When i click the link the timer goes crazy, doesn´t reset properly.

Anybody knows what´s the rigth way to reset countdown?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are missing a `clearInterval` otherwise you are creating a new interval each time you click on the element.

```js
let interval = null;

function timer(){
    var timer = 60 * 5, minutes, seconds;

    if (interval !== null) {
        clearInterval(interval);
    }

    interval = setInterval(function () {
        minutes = parseInt(timer / 60, 10)
        seconds = parseInt(timer % 60, 10);

        minutes = minutes < 10 ? "0" + minutes : minutes;
        seconds = seconds < 10 ? "0" + seconds : seconds;

        $('#time').text("Tiempo restante para actualización de datos " + minutes + ":" + seconds);

        if (--timer < 0) {
            timer = duration;
        }
    }, 1000);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use clearInterval inside setInterval itself

```
function timer(){
    var timer = 60 * 5, minutes, seconds;

    interval = setInterval(()=> {
        minutes = parseInt(timer / 60, 10)
        seconds = parseInt(timer % 60, 10);

        minutes = minutes < 10 ? "0" + minutes : minutes;
        seconds = seconds < 10 ? "0" + seconds : seconds;

        $('#time').text("Tiempo restante para actualización de datos " + minutes + ":" + seconds);

        if (--timer < 0) {
            timer = duration;
        }

         if (interval !== null) clearInterval(interval);
    }, 1000);
}
```